# How many parts were in Advent calendars of yore?

Tags: sets, shopping, advent-calendar

Is there any convenient way to find out how many pieces were in previous years' Advent calendars?  I looked through a dozen calendars on bricklink and most of them do not include the part count in the picture.  I was only able to find:

- [2010 City](https://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?S=2824-1&name=Advent%20Calendar%202010,%20City&category=%5BHoliday%5D%5BAdvent%5D%5BCity%5D#T=S&O=%7B%7D) - 271 pieces

I started looking for this because the 2015 Advent Calendars range from 233-292 pieces so I wanted to know what was typical for prior years.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find an overview of all advent calenders with piece count in this link

http://brickset.com/sets/tag-Advent-Calendar